# why ProcessCmdKey() does not handle focus of controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application shown on this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gP_ZzFP7IRw&feature=youtu.be) has a **numericupdown** control `numericupdown3` in a **groupbox** and outside of the group box has some other **textboxes**. when the cursor is in **numericupdown** control and when i hit tab it should move the cursor to `textbox3` i.e. the first textbox under the groupbox. But instead it moves to `tbx3` i.e. the second textbox under the groupbox. as shown on video i have used `processCmdKey()` to handle but still it does not move the cursor to `textbox3`. Funny thing is in code it shows currently **active control** as `textbox3` but on the form the cursor blinks on `tbx3`. is there away to fix this? i have also set the tab order all shown on video.

here is the animated gif of the youtube video

[image]

Here is the code in ProcessCmdKey() event and note that i have set the tab order, numericupdown3 -> 1, textbox3 --> 2 and tbx3 --> 3 and have disbled and set the TabStop to false in all other textbox controls

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Tab)
    {
        if (this.ActiveControl.Name == numericUpDown3.Name)
        {
            this.ActiveControl = this.textBox3;
            Console.WriteLine(this.ActiveControl.Name);
        }

    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

PS- i use VS 2010 (no SPs installed)

Comment: Please add some minimal code into your question that reproduces the problem. It's difficult to diagnose a problem through a video (which I can't see from work anyway since youtube is blocked)

Comment: Have you had a look at the tab order of your controls?

Comment: @SteveMitcham i have updated the post with some code

Comment: @BerndLinde yes numericupdown3 is 1, textbox3 is 2 and tbx3 is 3

Comment: Are the controls in different panels/groupboxes?

Comment: @BerndLinde the numericupddown is in a groupbox but all others are outside of group box and they are just on the form

Comment: Might it be possible to convert the video into a gif? I am intrigued and would like to help, but feel that without seeing the video I am missing something (youtube blocked at the office)

Comment: @BerndLinde atm im converting the youtube to gif i will update the post with gif asap : )

Comment: @BerndLinde i have updated the post with the animated gif : )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73426/discussion-between-bernd-linde-and-phill-greggan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73426/discussion-between-bernd-linde-and-phill-greggan):

### The solution:

Reset the tab-index of your controls accordingly to what you want them to be.
Each container (panel, groupbox, etc) has their underlying control's TabIndex start at 0.

In VisualStudio there is also a handy too to visually see the TabIndex of the entire form ( <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Tab Order</kbd>)

After doing this, remove the `ProcessCmdKey` event, since that will mess with the tab order later on again.

As mentioned in the chat also, ensure that you are checking the TabIndex of all the controls, even those hidden behind other controls!

### The dirty method when all else fails (Not recommended, but maybe useful to know):

One (dirty) way of allowing the tabbing to work correctly is by changing the ProcessCmdKey() event handler to the code below (**Read the warning below the code**):

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
  if (keyData == Keys.Tab)
  {
    if (this.ActiveControl.Name == numericUpDown3.Name)
    {
      this.ActiveControl = this.textBox3;
      Console.WriteLine(this.ActiveControl.Name);
      return true; // Stop the processing of additional key presses
    }

  }
  return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

**Warning:**
What that `return true` does is it prevents any additional KeyPress events from firing. So use it with caution and care, test your code after you implement the change to ensure everything still functions as planned.

The optimal (and clean) fix for this problem would be figuring out why the tabbing order is not adhered to in this case. When that is done, then the handling of the `ProcessCmdKey()` event should be removed and the normal tabbing order be allowed to flow.